# How do I remove the glow from particles

Tags: particles

I've setup a plane with a particle emitter system. When I render the footage and the particles are glowing. Where do I find the settings for that?

Comment: You're rendering the particles as halos (the default). You can render a sphere object for every particle if you set the render type to "Object" in the particle settings, then select a sphere object in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by CharlesL,
that glow is caused when the particles are rendered with *Halo* selected in *Particle settings > Render*:

[image]

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles):

> Particles may be rendered as:
>
> Halos (for Flames, Smoke, Clouds).
>       Meshes which in turn may be animated (e.g. fish, bees, …). In these cases, each particle “carries” another object.
>       Strands (for Hair, Fur, Grass); the complete way of a particle will be shown as a strand. These strands can be manipulated in the 3D
>   window (combing, adding, cutting, moving, etc).

To render a surface, you can change the rendered type to *Object* (to render a copy of an object in place of the particle) or *Group* (to randomly select the object from a group of objects)

You can change the halo settings by adding a [halo material](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Special_Effects/Halos) to the emitter object and changing the *Material* setting to the appropriate value in *Particle settings > Render*

The other options are

- **None** 
  fairly self-explanatory, do not render particles
- **Line** 
  Render a line along the vector of the particle
- **Path** 
  Used with [hair particles](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Hair)
- **[Billboard](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Physics/Particles/Visualization#Billboard)** 
  Render 2D planes at a fixed angle to the camera